# Shortcode exclude category

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

How can I exclude only one category from my homepage?

This is one **shortcode** that I'm using to show the newest posts

```
[vc_row][vc_column][td_block_big_grid category_id="22" sort="newest_posts"][/vc_column][/vc_row]
```

But it shows even the posts I don't want them to be there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FOUND solution:

What I did was to add on **category_id** the negative number of the category.
For example, I had `category_id="22"` and then, added another category `category_id="22, 23"` and both categories showed up.

After, I changed it to `category_id="-22, 23"` which made the posts from category 22 to not show up.